# SV: Error llegal combination of procedural drivers

Tags: driver, system-verilog, synthesis

Getting a `SV: Error illegal combination of procedural drivers` error with the below code, any idea how to resolve this?  The values of temp range from 0 to 3.

```
    module multi_driver_check ();
    reg [7:0] ll_data_map[3:0];
    reg [7:0] data_in[3:0];
    reg [7:0] temp[3:0];
    assign data_in = '{default:0};
    genvar map_i;
    for(map_i=0;map_i<4;map_i++)
    begin
      always_comb
      begin
        if(temp[map_i]==0)
          ll_data_map[0] = data_in[map_i];
        else if(temp[map_i]==1)
          ll_data_map[1] = data_in[map_i];
        else if(temp[map_i]==2)
          ll_data_map[2] = data_in[map_i];
        else
          ll_data_map[3] = data_in[map_i];
     end 
    end
   endmodule
```

Comment: `assign ll_data_map = data_in;` this is a simple statement if u want to pass data_in to ll_data_map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reason for Error:**
A generate for-loop unravels the code it encapsulates with in it at elaboration time of compile. `always_comb` make sure that anything it assigns is not assigned anywhere else. In your code is compiled, you effectively have 4 `always_comb`s assigning `ll_data_map` which is illegal.

**Solution:**
Move the for-loop inside the `always_comb` (`map_i` cannot be a `genvar`). This way all assignments to `ll_data_map` is done by a single `always_comb`.

**Other Note:**
`ll_data_map` is not a combinational logic even thought it is defined in an `always_comb`. The best tools will flag this; worst case it will fail to synthesize because the target devices does not support latches.
To make it proper combinational logic, you could add `ll_data_map = '{default:'0};` (or some other deterministic assignment) before starting the for-loop.
If `ll_data_map` is intended to be a latch, then use `always_latch` instead of `always_comb`. *(In general RTL design, latches are discouraged but are necessary for certain functionality)*

Answer (score 0):

generate statement just duplicates or conditionally adds/excludes statement in it body. In your case it generates multiple `always_comb` blocks, like the following:

```
always_comb
      begin
        if(temp[0]==0)
          ll_data_map[0] = data_in[0];
        else if(temp[0]==1)
          ll_data_map[1] = data_in[0];
        else if(temp[0]==2)
          ll_data_map[2] = data_in[0];
        else
          ll_data_map[3] = data_in[0];
     end
always_comb
      begin
        if(temp[1]==0)
          ll_data_map[0] = data_in[1];
        else if(temp[1]==1)
          ll_data_map[1] = data_in[1];
        else if(temp[1]==2)
          ll_data_map[2] = data_in[1];
        else
          ll_data_map[3] = data_in[1];
     end

...
```

as you can see `ll_data_map[0]` (and others) is driven at least 4 times from different always blocks. This is illegal.

My guess is that you do not need any generate block here and just need to move your for loop inside the always block:

```
int map_i;
always_comb begin
  for(map_i=0;map_i<4;map_i++)
    begin
        if(temp[map_i]==0)
          ll_data_map[0] = data_in[map_i];
        else if(temp[map_i]==1)
          ll_data_map[1] = data_in[map_i];
        else if(temp[map_i]==2)
          ll_data_map[2] = data_in[map_i];
        else
          ll_data_map[3] = data_in[map_i];
     end 
 end
```

Comment: Hi Serge, With your suggestion, the multiple driver issue is resolved, but on synthesis latch inferred error flagged, which was resolved via adding ll_data_map = '{default:'0};  before starting the for-loop.

Comment: right, i did not pay attention to it. Greg addressed it in his answer.